# What would be the other solution without being $x = 0$?

Tags: analysis

$\sin (x) = 0.703x$
  What would be the other solution without being $x=0$?

Comment: What is Sen here?

Comment: sin (x) = 0.703x

Comment: this can only be found numerically

Comment: how would you do?

Comment: @GoGogameRJ You would guess, and use clever algorithms to refine that guess until you have as many decimal places as you want. Getting an exact answer is not something I expect to be possible.

Comment: You do not have to arrive at the answer itself. I wanted you to show me the way, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Analytical answer:**

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\text{sinc}(x)=0.703$$

so that

$$x=\pm\text{ sinc}^{-1}(0.703)$$ where the cardinal sine is restricted to its main lobe, positive side.

---

**Approximate answer:**

Using the Taylor development of the sine to the fifth order,

$$1-\frac{x^2}6+\frac{x^4}{120}\approx0.703$$

This is a biquadratic equation, which gives the real roots

$$x\approx\pm1.406.$$

We can proceed with one Newton's iteration,

$$x'=x-\frac{\sin(x)-0.703x}{\cos(x)-0.703}\approx1.402352$$

Comment: I do not think it's going to work that way.  Is not it better to do a few interactions?

Comment: I'm in doubt ....

Comment: @GoGameRJ "I do not think it's going to work that way": can you substantiate ?

Comment: relax my wise warrior!  I'm really in doubt

Comment: @GoGameRJ: the fact is that I have no idea what you mean. Please explain.

Comment: Opa! Agora  entendi! Obrigado pela resolução

Comment: @GoGameRJ: Então você pode aceitar minha resposta.

Comment: can i use newton-raphson or gauss seidel?

Comment: @GoGameRJ: of course, Newton-Raphson is welcome, and you have a good starting value. Gauss-Seidel is quite irrelevant here.

Comment: Last question, master. Why is Gauss-Seidel irrelevant?

Comment: @GoGameRJ read Gauss-Seidel on Wikipedia.